# MySQL : Update some fields depending on each other

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a table with 16 fields as User1, User2, ... User16, ( + some other fields ) , I have a stored procedure named "Register" that get a "User Name" and put it in the first Null field of those 16 fields, for example if User1 and User2 have value, new "User Name" will put in User3, there is no problem

I have another stored procedure named "UnRegister" that get a "User Name" and set to Null the value of field that have given "User Name"

There is no problem in Updating table and putting Null for given "User Name" but the problem is after Updating User(X) to Null, User(X+1) value should put in User(X) field !

An example :

```
User1 = "U1"
User2 = "U2"
User3 = "U3"
User4 = "U4"
User5 = NULL
...
User16 = NULL
```

Now , I want to Unregister "U2" and the result values should be like this :

```
User1 = "U1"
User2 = "U3"
User3 = "U4"
User4 = NULL
User5 = NULL
...
User16 = NULL
```

I think, I should use 16 CASE statement in an UPDATE statement for all 16 fields and 16 WHEN for each CASE !!

Is there another way to do that ?!

thanks ...

Comment: Instead of setting user(x) to null, why not set it to user(x+1) immediately?  Then do whatever you need to do to user(x+1).

Comment: OK, I set user(X) value to User(X+1) immediately but what about next fields ?!

Comment: It sounds to me like you should be rethinking the design of your DB and using proper one to many tables. It sounds to me that you are usually fields where you should use a one to many relationship. I understand if you can't change the schema now for whatever reason, but fixing the schema probably should be the first place to start working on this problem.

Comment: I concur with @PressingOnAlways that you should rearrange your table(s) so that there is only one `user` column. Look for tutorials on "Database Normalization" on the internet. For a starter, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191178(v=sql.105).aspx and take note of dot point 4 : _A table should not have repeating values or columns_.